# Inhibition of beta-oxidation by acetyl- or malonyl-CoA

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism

> Which molecule, in excess, inhibits beta-oxidation?
>
> a. Acetyl-CoA
>
> b. Malonyl-CoA

The answer to this question seems debatable to me, as I think both are correct.  However, according to my professor, only one is correct — which one I  don’t know because it was a question from the final exam.

Acety-CoA can inhibit thiolase, and malonyl-CoA can inhibit CAT I (Carnitine- acyltransferase), both of which lead to the same outcome — inhibiting beta-oxidation

Answer (score 2):

Mammalian $\beta$-oxidation occurs in the mitochondrion, whereas fatty acid biosynthesis is cytoplasmic.

- The rate-limiting in mammalian fatty acid oxidation is considered to be [carnitine palmitoyltransferase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnitine_O-acetyltransferase) (CAT), a key enzyme in the transport of acetyl-CoA across the inner mitochondrial membrane.  This enzyme is inhibited by low micromolar concentrations of malonyl-CoA (see [Beta oxidation of fatty acids](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000527609190015A) by H. Schulz).

Malonyl-CoA, of course, is a key intermediate in *fatty acid biosynthesis*.  [Salih Wakil](http://www.jbc.org/content/281/5/e5) showed that CO<sub>2</sub>  is required for fatty acid biosynthesis, but that carbon atoms from CO<sub>2</sub>  do not appear in fatty acids, and it is now known that this is due to the formation of .malonyl-CoA by acetyI-CoA carboxylase, the rate-limiting reaction of fatty acid synthesis.

- Thus when fatty acid biosynthesis is taking place, the concentration of malonyl-CoA is high and CAT (and therefore $\beta$-oxidation) is inhibited ([Schulz, 1991](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000527609190015A)).

However, as the OP points out, micromolar concentrations of acetyl-CoA inhibit [3-ketoacyI-CoA thiolase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiolase) when the concentration of CoASH is low, and the Acetyl-CoA/CoASH ratio within the mitochondrion may also play a role in the regulation of beta-oxidation ([Schulz, 1991](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000527609190015A)).

As the OP says, it is a debatable point, and it seems to me, an example of a badly worded exam question.  I think the 'expected' answer is probably malonyl-CoA, and there is no doubt that this molecule plays a key role in the regulation of both fatty acid oxidation and fatty acid biosynthesis.  Nevertheless, the inhibition of thiolase by Acetyl-CoA may also play a role in the regulation of beta-oxidation.

Perhaps your Professor is an example of the [type](https://books.google.ie/books?id=hwnnjdJhPIcC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=warburg+go+attach+yourself+to+some+asshole+of+a+professor&source=bl&ots=rEqtUnaZL5&sig=tbgg285KCmJSRRqUz_ELPxD3NL4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtxqWhnajfAhXBXhUIHdcKAqkQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=warburg%20go%20attach%20yourself%20to%20some%20asshole%20of%20a%20professor&f=false) that [Warburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Heinrich_Warburg) told Hans [Krebs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Adolf_Krebs) to attach himself to? :-)

Comment: Your Google books link tells me I have reached a page I cannot access. Perhaps you can give us the Warburg quotation, in the German original if possible.

Comment: Taken me a while to get to it, but I finally found the quotation in Krebs’ (English language) autobiography of 1981, [*Reminiscences and Reflections*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Reminiscences-Reflections-Hans-Krebs/dp/0198547021). On p. 26 he gives this account of his interview with Warburg “I could learn a lot in his laboratory, he said, but if it were my aim to make a university career, ‘Then you had better attach yourself to some old ass of a professor.’” He goes on to write: “Warburg kept his word on both counts: he taught me a great deal, and he did not actively help me find a post…”